# T-SQL: can't seem to set variables immediately after declaring them

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have looked through countless posts on declaring/setting variables in a sql script.  But most seem to involve syntax errors or using exec commands. The script I am trying to execute is quite simple - so I am having a hard time understanding why I cant set values.

Here is the SQL:

```
declare @counter int = 1,
        @batchSize int = 100000,
        @tableRows int,
        @totalBatches int;

set @tableRows= (select count(distinct chFileVersionID) from IRISDocuments)
set @totalBatches = (ceiling((@tableRows / @batchSize)));

--print some stuff

while @counter <= @totalBatches
begin
 . . . loop logic that only uses @counter variable for incrementing 
end
```

The error I get is

> Must declare the scalar variable "@tableRows"

which is clearly declared directly above. I have tried setting values with a select statement, as well as declaring each variable individually, and declaring and setting value in the same statement with no avail.

Comment: Try just executing the initial DECLARE and SET portion before the WHILE. Does running just that complete successfully?

Comment: The first part of your code works just fine, it seems like the error comes from a line in the rest of you code which is not provided in your question.

Comment: My guess is this could be rewritten without using loops. Not only would it fix your variable issue it would be a lot faster and easier to maintain.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Agree with @Sami tried your code on my tables and it works just fine. where your print is commented out. Just print both your variables or all and see their value(s).

Comment: Do you have a `create procedure` right above that code, that is not followed by a `begin`?

Comment: Do you have a `go` separating batches?  That would affect variable scoping.

Comment: You are probably referencing the variable inside a dynamic SQL statement somewhere below. That would fall into the "out of scope" scenario. If you need to supply your variable to a dynamic SQL statement, you need a parameterised `sp_executesql` call set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

The above actually works (I mean testing without the WHILE loop of course).

2 possible source of the error if the variable is not exactly used as above:

1. Using a variable to define another variable in the same declaration

E.g.:

```
declare @counter int = 1,
        @batchSize int = 100000,
        @tableRows int = 10000000000000,
        @totalBatches int = (ceiling((@tableRows / @batchSize)))
```

This won't work and produces your error - within a statement the order of execution is not row-by-row, so you can not give a value to @totalBatches as at that point @tableRows is not implemented yet.

2. Trying to use a variable that is out of scope
   If this is a query that contains the GO batch separator then after that all variables before GO are out of scope.

E.g.:

```
declare @counter int = 1,
        @batchSize int = 100000,
        @tableRows int,
        @totalBatches int;

SELECT @counter, @batchSize, @tableRows, @totalBatches int
GO


SELECT @counter, @batchSize, @tableRows, @totalBatches int
```

The second SELECT will throw your error.